# Updating data using fetch

Tags: javascript, python, fetch, fastapi, put

I have a problem with data updates using Rest API, fetch and Jinja2. When I call the put request, the update is successful, as shown in bash, but the data in the database itself is not updated.

update_post_by_id.py:

```
async def update_post_by_id(id:int, post: UpdatePost, owner_id: int, db: Session):
    post_in_db = db.query(Post).filter(Post.id == id).first()
    if not post_in_db:
        return 
    post_in_db.title = post.title
    post_in_db.text = post.text
    post_in_db.image = post.image
    db.add(post_in_db)
    db.commit()
    return post_in_db
```

update_post.py(everything works in this code, because it is apis):

```
@router.put("/update-post/{id}")
async def update_post(
id: int,
title: str = Form(None),
text: str = Form(None),
image: UploadFile = File(None), 
db: Session = Depends(get_db),
current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user_from_token)
):
    post = await retreive_post(id=id, db=db)
    if not post:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"Post with id {id} does not exist",
        )
    print(post.owner_id, current_user.id, current_user.is_superuser)
    if post.owner_id == current_user.id or current_user.is_superuser:
        post_update = UpdatePost(
        title=title, text=text
        )
        if not title:
            post_update.title = Post.title
        if not text:
            post_update.text = Post.text
        if not image:
            post_update.image = Post.image
        elif image:
            post_update.image = await handle_file_upload(image)
        message = await update_post_by_id(id=id, post=post_update, db=db, 
                  owner_id=current_user.id)
        return {"detail":"Successfully updated data."}
     raise HTTPException(
     status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="You are not permitted!!!!"
     )
```

update_post.py(jinja2):

```
@router.get("/update-post/{id}")           
async def update_post(id: int, request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    post = await retreive_post(id=id, db=db)
    if not post:
        return templates.TemplateResponse("posts/not_found_post.html", 
        {"request": request})
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
    "posts/update_post.html", {"request": request, "post": post}
    )
```

update_post.html(Already here the problems with updating the data begin, namely with fetch):

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="update">
    <div id="result" class="text-danger text-bold lead"></div>
    <h2>Update a post</h2>
    <div class="errors">
      {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{error}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="inputFile">
        <input type="file" name="image" value="{{post.image}}" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" value="{{post.title}}" name="title" autocomplete="off">
        <span>Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <textarea name="text" autocomplete="off">{{post.text}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <a onclick="updatePost({{post.id}})" class="btn btn-primary">Update post</a>
      <!-- <input type="submit" value="Update post"> -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
  async function updatePost(id){
      await fetch("/posts/update-post/"+id,{  
          method:'PUT',})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Refreshing...")
      .then(data => document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = data.detail);
  }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

There are definitely no problems with the token, I'm sure of that.